# Need some explanation regarding memory bytes in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have 2 examples given:
Example 1:
[image]

I understand that EAX stores 00 00 00 2A becasue 02Ah is 42d in hex.

And here is the second example:
[image]

Can anyone explain why there is ?? ?? FF FE and what is has to do with -2 ?

Thank you

Comment: Read up on two's complement representation.

Comment: The reason for the `??` is b/c the `mov bx,-2` does not modify the upper 16-bits of `ebx`. -2 in 16-bits is `FFFE`, so in little endian memory, `FE FF`.  We cannot index registers so despite the overlapping nature of `bl` & `bh`, with `bx` & `ebx`, there is no issue or question of endian until a multi-byte value is written to memory (as memory, being indexable, does have endian-ness as a property).